# How to connect bluetooth mouse to the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I want to connect bluetooth mouse with one of my iOS app.

I search a lot for that and I found that without jailbreaking, iOS does not have mouse support.

So, is it true? if yes then is there any way to connect any external Bluetooth device with the iOS app?

Comment: You *can* connect certain external bluetooth devices, such as speakers or keyboards. However, I'm pretty positive you can *not* connect bluetooth mice.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I used the external Accessory framework but it didn't search keyboard. So did you guide me how to connect external bluetooth devices?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way your magic mouse would connect to your iOS device. magic mouse needs OSX lion or higher. iOS is just not compitable with mice.

In short, without jailbreaking, iOS does not have mouse support.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How can I connect any other bluetooth device with ios app?

Comment: have a look at this project: https://github.com/quickies/BluetoothScanner.ios

Comment: @iosBhavikitt if you find my answer right, please mark it as correct to close this question! Thanks!